# Norms in normed spaces are always assumed to be finite? But where are infinite norms then?

Tags: normed-spaces

Norms in normed spaces are always assumed to be finite? True? But where are infinite norms then?

This is the "background" that I have been presented as to why questioning the finiteness of Cauchy-Schwarz etc. in normed spaces is unreasonable. Because $\mathbb{R}$ doesn't have $\pm \infty$. That while one may construct infinite sums inside norms, then in normed spaces they're not assumed to exist.

Where do then, however, infinite norms exist?

Comment: Presumably "a norm is a real number"  leaves your question iunanswered?

Comment: @timtfj Yes because my idea is that what if one considers infinite sums of positive terms inside norms, then intuitively such could attain infinite value and then ...?

Comment: Doesn't that apply to all divergent series, though? So the sum is simply undefined if the series doesn't have a limit, meaning the norm isn't defined either in that situation . . .?

Comment: @timtfj But what if one extends the norm definition to include $\infty$? However perhaps the reason of omiting it is that such norms would have no practical use?

Comment: Got it. :-) I don't feel competent to answer, but hopefully this has clarified it enough avoid answers which ignore what you mean.